# Delphi null parameter in where

Tags: sql, delphi, parameters, zeos

I have two ZQuery's - master and details, linked via detail.DataSource and sql parameters.

Master sql:

```
select key1, key2 from list
```

Details sql:

```
select * from list where key1=:key1 and key2=:key2
```

The problem is that when key2 is null the details is empty!

How do I get the parameters here work with null link fields?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL uses 3-valued logic. All your boolean values can have 3 states: true, false and null (undefined). The null is a false value is a where clause. You can look up for the thruth tables for this logic [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic#Kleene_and_Priest_logics).

In the expression `key1=:key1 and key2=:key2`, if any of the columns have null value, the whole expression evaluates to null.

I advise you to use the `IS DISTINCT FROM` or `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` operators if your DBMS supports them. They can return only true or false, even if one of their argument is null.

Basically `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` is the more [readable and standard](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/not-distinct) way of writing `x = y OR (x IS NULL AND y IS NULL)`.

Comment: Well written and good advice, though it's only about `key2` here and so long it is the same table, it's enough to ask if `IS NULL` or they equal.

Answer (score 2):

Then try to add into your **WHERE** clause a condition that allows you to fetch also tuples that are at **NULL** state in their field:

```sql
SELECT
   *
FROM
   LIST
WHERE
   KEY1 = :KEY1 AND
   (KEY2 IS NULL OR KEY2 = :KEY2)
```

Comment: Yeah, that was my quick workaround before I asked the question